# Log4Cplus - change levels to be logged in different functions?

Tags: c++, logging, properties, log4cplus

I have a basic question about log4cplus.

Is it possible to make two objects like:

```
"logger myLogVar"
"logger myLogVar2"
```

And then, from the property file, change the logging level for each variable individually. I want this so I can turn off logging for a single function during runtime by updating the property file with:

```
"log4cplus::ConfigureAndWatchThread watcher( logFileName.c_str(), 5*1000 );"
```

I don't know how to configure my property file and C++ file to solve the problem. Anyone good at this?

Comment: I don't get your problem.  Just have separate loggers, and change the level to OFF if you want to disable the logging.  What problem are u facing?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes what you describe is what i want, but I don't now how to init a specific logger with a specific property file?

Comment: to be clerer, i want only to change the level for one logger, not both. And this by change the property file. Cant find how to do this.

Comment: There is only one "property" file, which is the logging config.  In Log4* family, you can always configure loggers' level individually.  I don't understand what is the difficulties you are facing

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

In the property file:

log4cplus.logger.myTest=DEBUG, FILEAPPENDER

In .cpp:

Logger log = getInstance("myTest");

Then just change the level inte the property file while system running to change de logging output.